# Choose where to save the file in Photoshop Scripts

Tags: photoshop-script

I have this piece of photoshop script.

I already have the input folder be prompted.

How do I make this script prompt me for the output location? To either

1. choose where to save the file and with what name, or
2. choose to save the script in the same location as the analysis files?

```js
#target photoshop

app.bringToFront()
main()

function main() {

    var inputFolder = Folder.selectDialog("Please select folder to process ")
    if (inputFolder == null) return

    var fileList = inputFolder.getFiles(
        /\.(jpg|dng|tif|psd|crw|cr2|psb|exr|nef|dcr|dc2|erf|raf|orf|tga|mrw|mos|srf|pic|pct|pxr|pdd|pef|png|x3f|rw2)$/i)

    // var outFile = new File(Folder.desktop + "/" + decodeURI(inputFolder.name) + ".csv")

    outFile.open('w')
    outFile.writeln(
        "Filename,Mean Bleu,Mean Marron, Mean Jaune, Mean Noir, Mean Rose, Mean Relief\r ")

    for (var a in fileList) {

        // open(fileList)
        open(fileList[a])

        // var area = activeDocument.histogram
        // var luminosity = activeDocument.histogram
        // CMYK Channel  
        /*-------------------------------------------------------------*/

        activeDocument.channels["COBALT"].visible = true
        var Bleu = activeDocument.channels["COBALT"].histogram
        var mean_Bleu = 0
        var total_Bleu = 0
        for (var n_Bleu = 0; n_Bleu < Bleu.length; n_Bleu++) {
            total_Bleu = total_Bleu + Bleu[n_Bleu]
        }
        for (var m_Bleu = 0; m_Bleu < Bleu.length; m_Bleu++) {
            var Value_Bleu = Bleu[m_Bleu]
            mean_Bleu = mean_Bleu + (m_Bleu * Value_Bleu / total_Bleu)
        }


        /*-------------------------------------------------------------*/

        // omitted code for other channels

        /*-------------------------------------------------------------*/

        //(Bleu).toFixed(0))
        outFile.writeln(decodeURI(activeDocument.name) + "," + (mean_Bleu) + ","
                + (mean_Marron) + "," + (mean_Jaune) + "," + (mean_Noir) + ","
                + (mean_Rose) + "," + (mean_Relief) + "\r")

        app.activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES)
    }

    outFile.close()

    alert("Process complete\nCSV created...\n" + decodeURI(outFile))

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place the files in the same folder. I'm working on the assumption you are working through lots of images and putting that date into one file.

```
var inputFolder = Folder.selectDialog("Please select folder to process ")

var docName = "myHistogram"; // rename your file here
var outFile = new File(inputFolder + "//" + docName + ".csv")
alert(outFile);
```

I don't think you can open a save as dialogue for another file type. Photoshop wasn't designed to save out CSV files ;)
This is a function to to save the image file. You could then extract the path and use that to save the CSV file.

```
save_file_dialog(); 

function save_file_dialog()
{
   if (documents.length == 0)
{
   alert("No documents to save");
   return
}
try
   { 
      var ad = new ActionDescriptor();
      executeAction( charIDToTypeID( "save" ), ad, DialogModes.ALL );
   }
catch(e)
   {
      alert("Could not save file");
   } 
};
```